# Unable to remove the $ sign named files using linux?

Tags: linux, files, rm, special-characters

Here is my `ls` command, which shows the list of files in my current directory:

```
rper:  ls -l

$commandoutput[0]  
file.txt
```

I tried to remove `$commandoutput[0]` line by using `rm -rf $commandoutput[0]`, but it shows the following error. How can I remove it?

```
rper: rm -rd $commandoutput[0]
commandoutput: Undefined variable.
```

Comment: If you are new to the shell and have filenames with "special characters" (like `$`, `*` whitespaces, newlines and so on), it's generally a good idea to quote them: `rm -rd '$commandoutput[0]'` to avoid nay shell "magic"

Comment: @Philippos : it is what should be used in the command line. And then he should look for which script used a : `> '$commandoutput[0]'` as well

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Escape `$` (and desirably `[`, `]`) sign in your file name with backslash `\`:

```
rm -rf \$commandoutput\[0\]
```

Comment: (also, in many shells tab completion will do that escaping for you once you're far enough to complete, which in this case means at least beyond the `\$`.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz and, in `zsh` with `setopt complete_in_word`, you can tab-complete from anywhere in the filename, so something like `comm<TAB>` would work, no need to even type `\$`!

Comment: honestly, that's the thing I can't understand - why so primitive answers gained so many upvotes? I wish more complex solutions gained many upvotes as well (a lot more deserving than this case)

Answer (score 27):

In alternative to @RomanPerekhrest's answer, this will also work:

```
rm '$commandoutput[0]'
```

as the single quotes will avoid variable expansion.

Another way is to start typing `rm $` and then hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>; the shell will autocomplete the filename, escaping characters as needed.

Comment: `rm $<tab>` tries to autocomplete with variable names for me, in `bash` and `zsh`. I need to escape the `$` first, i.e. `rm \$<tab>` or `rm '$<tab>`.

Comment: It's better to use `Alt`+`/` instead of `Tab` — then the autocompletion will work _only_ on file names.

Answer (score 2):

While others have answered this question, another way to do this would be by finding the inode of the file and using find and exec delete to remove the file.

```
ls -il
```

Sample Output:

```
781956 drwx------  3 viv viv 4096 2017-07-7 15:05 $commandoutput[0]
```

The first column should be the inode, in the above example, run:

```
find . -inum 781956 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way is to use a wildcard and rm -i:

```
rm -i *command*
```

This will, for all the filenames containing the word "command", ask you if you want to remove the file. You can then check before deletion.